# systemverilog, signal concatenation

Tags: concatenation, vhdl, record, system-verilog

I have a VHDL record in the design e.g

```
   TYPE  signal_record IS RECORD
          signal_0  : std_ulogic;
          signal_1  : std_ulogic;
 ...
          signal_31  : std_ulogic;
   END RECORD;
```

On my SV testbench, I would like to apply an assertion on each of the signal_%d in systemverilog.

```
generate
    for (genvar i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        begin : 
            assert property(pp_one_property(clk, {`PATH_TO_SIGNAL.signal_,i}));
        end
endgenerate
```

However this won't work, as systemverilog would expect a signal as the second argument of the assertion property.

Is there a trick how to apply assertion dynamically on such signals?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write all of them by hand, unfortunately. The concatenation operator doesn't create new identifiers. If you were to have your record as an array instead of 32 individual fields, you could maybe do it because you would be able to index the entries based on the `genvar`.

Comment: It's easy to do this from Python... the joys of dynamic languages :)

Comment: @chiggs Or languages that have reflection.

Comment: Indeed - macros can only get you so far (see UVM source code).  Verification benefits greatly from reflection / introspection capability so it's a pity that so much effort is invested in SystemVerilog.

Comment: It's a pity people still have a need to declare a list of signals as scalars instead of making them an array as it should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog allows you to construct identifiers from text macros w/o introducing white spaces by using two consecutive grave accent (i.e. ``). This is probably the closest you get to what you want.